# remove row in excel when match found and criteria satisfied

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code which I have adapted which checks for a specific value in a cell in 2 worksheets and if there is a match it deletes the entire row from the first worksheet. This works fine but I need to refine the code. I need to check the second worksheet column E to see if there is "YES" in the cell, if there is a match in worksheet 2 column A and worksheet 1 column A and there is also a "Yes" in worksheet 2 column E then the row in worksheet 1 containing the match in column A should be deleted.
This is the code I have at the moment I just can not work out the `and` bit to check column E worksheet 2, hopefully someone will be able to help out.

**Current Code**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()

Dim uprn1 As Range
Dim uprn2 As Range, rngtodel As Range, c As Range
Dim lastrow As Long

With Worksheets("Enum 1")
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
    Set uprn1 = .Range("a2:a" & lastrow)
End With

Set uprn2 = Worksheets("results1").Range("a:a")
For Each c In uprn1

    If Not IsError(Application.Match(c.value, uprn2, 0)) Then
    'if value from uprn1 is found in uprn2 then remember this cell for deleting

        If rngtodel Is Nothing Then
            Set rngtodel = c
        Else
            Set rngtodel = Union(rngtodel, c)
        End If

    End If
Next c

If Not rngtodel Is Nothing Then
    rngtodel.EntireRow.Delete
End If

End Sub
```

This of course may not be the best way to tackle this problem so any help would be greatfully received

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below :

```
Option Explicit 

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()

Dim uprn1 As Range
Dim uprn2 As Range, rngtodel As Range, c As Range
Dim lastrow As Long

With Worksheets("Enum 1")
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
    Set uprn1 = .Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
End With

Set uprn2 = Worksheets("results1").Range("A:A")
For Each c In uprn1

    If Not IsError(Application.Match(c.value, uprn2, 0)) Then
        Dim Rowmatch As Long
        Rowmatch = Application.Match(c.value, uprn2, 0)

        ' check if cell in Column E in the "Match" row found in the second worksheet value is "YES"
        If UCASE(Worksheets("results1").Range("E" & Rowmatch).value) = "YES" Then

            'if value from uprn1 is found in uprn2 then remember this cell for deleting
            If rngtodel Is Nothing Then
                Set rngtodel = c
            Else
                Set rngtodel = Union(rngtodel, c)
            End If
        End If

    End If
Next c

If Not rngtodel Is Nothing Then
    rngtodel.EntireRow.Delete
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Shai Rado, I tried your code and nothing happened, that is to say it ran but nothing was deleted from Enum1

Comment: @Graham you do have a "YES" value in Column E at worksheet2 ("results1") ?

Comment: yes I do, is the search case sensitive? as the value copied across is "Yes"

Comment: @Graham  there's a work around, use `UCASE` , see edited code

Comment: Thank you very much Shai Rado this has solved my problem, I have tried it a couple of times and it works. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

`If Not IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, uprn2, 0)) Then`

to

`If Not IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, uprn2, 0)) And Worksheets("results2").Range("E" & c.Row).Value = "YES" Then`

Comment: `c.Row` is the row of the cell location in "Enum 1" worksheet, and not the result of the `Match`. You need to get the row number in the second sheet where the `Match` was found, this is actualy the result of the `Match` Function. `Application.Match(c.value, uprn2, 0)` retruns the row number of the `Match` in the 2nd worksheet.

Comment: @ShaiRado Hmm, the question seems slightly ambiguous as to what data is on which worksheet, but your reading of it does seem more likely on reflection.

Answer (score 0):

edited to handle numbers as filtering values along with strings

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim uprn1() As String '<--| declare codes array as of "String" type

    uprn1 = GetArray '<--| use a helper function to fill the codes array and not to clutter "main" code

    With Worksheets("results1")
        With .Range("E1", .Cells(.Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its columns A to E cells from row 1 down to last column A not empty cell
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=uprn1, Operator:=xlFilterValues  '<--| filter it on its 1st column with 'uprn1' values
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any filtered cells other than headers
                .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="YES" '<--| filter it on its 5th column with "YES"
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete  '<--| delete filtered cells other than headers, if any
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| remove AutoFilter and show all rows back
    End With
End Sub

Function GetArray() As String()
    Dim iCell As Long

    With Worksheets("Enum 1")
        With .Range("a2", .Cells(.Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp))
            ReDim arr(1 To .Rows.count) As String
            For iCell = 1 To .Rows.count
                arr(iCell) = .Cells(iCell, 1).Value
            Next iCell
        End With
    End With
    GetArray = arr
End Function
```

Comment: Hello, I have also tried this code and this does not work either, so I am a bit puzzled you guys obviously know what you are talking about but it would seem that the codes does not work, so I am at a bit of a loss to understand why

Comment: I am a bit of a loss to understand what does "not work" mean, too. Give details

Comment: the code compiles and runs, when I run the userform it copies the value 10024191759 into column A on ws results1 and also copies the value "yes" into column "E". your code then ( I assume) reads Enum 1 and in column A  row 1225 the value 10024191759 is present, So because the value 10024191759 is in results1 column A and "yes" is in column E the row 1225 shold be deleted from enum1. I hope this makes sense thank you so much for you time

Comment: Just noticed is the search case sensitive? as the value passed to column "E" "Yes"

Comment: since `uprn1` values can be _numbers_, you have to declare `uprn1` as of `String` type and have `AutoFilter()` act on both numbers and strings. And , no, `AutoFilter()` is not case sensitive.

Comment: @Graham, did you get through it?

Comment: Hi there, again thanks for all your help, this kind of works, there are 2 problems. The row is deleted from worksheet results1, it should be deleted from worksheet Enum 1 and it also deletes the headers of the columns in worksheet results1 as well as the row data.

Comment: You are welcome. Since you already accepted a solution there's no need to go further here. Good coding